# Event time between two jsp windows

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

This might sound like an odd one but I have a jsp form that has an event timer on the page to keep the page active before logging the user out. After selecting some options it opens up a popup window where the user has to complete the form with further options.

The problem is that the first form can time out while the user is active on the second and I would like to somehow reset the timer on the first form if there is activation on the 2nd form. It would actually be enough to determine general mouse or keyboard activity on the original form even though it has lost focus.

Can this be done?

We are using a proprietary framework called Nordic Edge so I don't have a lot of scope to rebuild how the search and popup are implemented.